# div contenteditable="true"でユーザーに入力してもらった値の渡し方

Tags: jquery, html5

うまくいかないので教えてください。

まずこの枠内にユーザーに文字や画像を入力してもらいます。

```
<div id="editor" contenteditable="true"></div>
```

入力後このボタンをユーザーに押してもらうことをトリガに

```
<input type="buttun" onclick="add()">
```

jQueryを実行して、

```
function add() {
var editor = $("#editor").val();
$.mobile.changePage($("#list-page"));
$("#list").append("<li>” + "<p>" + editor + "</p></li>")
$("#list").listview('refresh');
};
```

以下のリストビューにユーザーが入力した内容を反映

```
<div data-role="page" id="list-page">
<ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" id="list"></ul>
</div>
```

という流れにしたいのですが、ボタンを押しても先に進めずに困っています。
上記のコードに何か間違いはあるでしょうか。

Comment: 「先に進めず」とはどういう症状なのでしょうか。

Comment: すみません、先へ進めない状況は回避できたのですが、div内にユーザーが入力した内容がリストビューに反映されず、白紙のリストだけ追加される状況です。

Answer (score 1):

[jQueryのリファレンス](http://api.jquery.com/val/)には`div`に`.val()`が使えるとは書いていません。おそらく、`.html()` などを使う必要があります。

Comment: .html を使うことによって、確かにうまく処理されるようになりました。知識不足でなぜなのかがよくわかりませんが、ありがとうございました。